# UICollectionView scroll issue with paging enabled after tap

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `collectionView` that returns back to the first cell when I tap a new cell in the second page.

Although it should be the second page, I am getting Page 0.0 in the second one and 0.0 in the first one too.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let pageWidth = collectionCustom.frame.size.width
        let page = floor((collectionCustom.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1

        print("Page number: \(page)")

    }
```

I have nothing happening in the `didSelectItem` method, so why am I getting that scroll?

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: (inout CGPoint)) {

        let pageWidth: Float = Float(collectionCustom.frame.width)
        // width + space
        let currentOffset: Float = Float(collectionCustom.contentOffset.x)
        let targetOffset: Float = Float(targetContentOffset.x)
        var newTargetOffset: Float = 0
        if targetOffset > currentOffset {
            newTargetOffset = ceilf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth
        }
        else {
            newTargetOffset = floorf(currentOffset / pageWidth) * pageWidth
        }
        if newTargetOffset < 0 {
            newTargetOffset = 0
        }
        else if newTargetOffset > Float(collectionCustom.contentSize.width) {
            newTargetOffset = Float(collectionCustom.contentSize.width)
        }

        targetContentOffset.x = CGFloat(currentOffset)
        collectionCustom.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(newTargetOffset), y: CGFloat(0)), animated: true)

        var index: Int = Int(newTargetOffset / pageWidth)

        var cell: UICollectionViewCell? = collectionCustom.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0))

        cell = collectionCustom.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: index + 1, section: 0))

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you add more description of the behavior you are experiencing and the desired behavior?

Comment: Nothing in the code you have put in the question is causing the problem. You'll need to include more code or try debugging it yourself and adding some more debug info.

Comment: I would like the `collectionView` to show 4 cells per page, which is doing correctly, but when I have between 5 and 7 cells, it won't display the next page in the log, and that's why I get scrolled back to the first cell. It works well with 8 objects and same with multiples of 4. Ideally, I would like to see 3 cells if I have 7 objects, and so on, but it keeps showing me 4 all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to current page than you should get you page from scrollview as this

```
 func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / collectionCustom.frame.width) // You can change width according you 
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)

}
```

Comment: @Christian Welcome mate